Why are MediaPlayer's event handlers not trigged when casting?
My code is based on Microsoft's official sample project: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/windows-universal-samples/basicmediacasting/
And my modified project is pushed to my Github repo.
https://github.com/tomxue/BasicMediaCasting/tree/master
Details:
For some reason I need to use MediaPlayer indstead of MediaElement in my UWP application. And I find that when no casting, each of the registered event handlers of MediaPlayer are trigged correctly. But when casting media to smart TV, then the registered event handler of MediaPlayer cannot be trigged or stably trigged.
(1) mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PositionChanged, mediaPlayer.MediaEnded events are not stably trigged. This can be reproduced by pressing below "Load Video" button for the second time of video playing. Or even when current playing is not finished, then press the "Load Video" button. Which means StartMediaPlayer() is executed again.
(2) mediaPlayer.VolumeChanged is never trigged.
Main code change is below:
private async void castingDevicesList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
     ...

     //Create a new casting connection to the device that's been selected
     connection = ((CastingDevice)castingDevicesList.SelectedItem).CreateCastingConnection();

     //Register for events
     connection.ErrorOccurred += Connection_ErrorOccurred;
     connection.StateChanged += Connection_StateChanged;

     //Cast the loaded video to the selected casting device.
     CastingSource source = mediaPlayer.GetAsCastingSource();
     await connection.RequestStartCastingAsync(source);
     }
}

private void StartMediaPlayer(TimeSpan position)
{
     mediaPlayer.Pause();
     mediaPlayer.Source = MediaSource.CreateFromUri(new Uri("ms-appx:///1.mp4"));
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.Position = position;
     mediaPlayer.Volume = 0.05;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalVideoSizeChanged -= MediaPlayer_PlaybackSession_NaturalVideoSizeChanged;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.NaturalVideoSizeChanged += MediaPlayer_PlaybackSession_NaturalVideoSizeChanged;
     mediaPlayer.MediaEnded -= MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
     mediaPlayer.MediaEnded += MediaPlayer_MediaEnded;
     mediaPlayer.MediaOpened -= MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
     mediaPlayer.MediaOpened += MediaPlayer_MediaOpened;
     mediaPlayer.VolumeChanged -= MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged;
     mediaPlayer.VolumeChanged += MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PositionChanged -= PlaybackSession_PositionChanged;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.PositionChanged += PlaybackSession_PositionChanged;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.MediaPlayer.VolumeChanged -= MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged2;
     mediaPlayer.PlaybackSession.MediaPlayer.VolumeChanged += MediaPlayer_VolumeChanged2;
     mediaPlayer.Play();
     Debug.WriteLine($"{nameof(StartMediaPlayer)}: from position: {position.TotalSeconds} s");
}

And please go to case 3) Casting Using Custom Picker like below picture shown to reproduce my issue. You need to click the "Load Video" Button to select whatever file, and it will play an embedded video.


Yes, it has many known issues for casting, I think you'd better post issue in UWP github issue box, it will get quickly response.

@NicoZhu Thank you for your reply! My reference code comes from this project: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/main/Samples/BasicMediaCasting   Do you mean to open a "New issue" there?
